# How to apply digitisation algorithm to raster

Tags: qgis, python, raster, digitizing

I am building a code to apply a digitisation algorithm into a raster and get the results in a shapefile. I built the code and it works, but I keep having issues with the resulting shapefile being misplaced. Even though the source raster is georeferenced the resulting shapefile has no geographic information, not even when I created the '.prj'.

This is the code I'm using:

```
crs = 'EPSG:3857'

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = -9214486.9219909626990557, 6036445.9014410832896829, -8969388.7271982412785292, 6482052.3726267348974943

edges = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry'])

for contour in contours:
    if len(contour) >= 3:
        polygon = Polygon([tuple(point[0]) for point in contour])
        gdf = gdf.append({'geometry': polygon}, ignore_index=True)

output_shapefile = 'output_shapefile'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

ds = driver.CreateDataSource(output_shapefile + '.shp')
layer = ds.CreateLayer(output_shapefile, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

field_defn = ogr.FieldDefn("ID", ogr.OFTInteger)
layer.CreateField(field_defn)

spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
spatial_ref.ImportFromEPSG(int(crs.split(':')[1]))

layer_defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
layer_defn.GetGeomFieldDefn(0).SetSpatialRef(spatial_ref)

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(row['geometry'].wkt)
    feature = ogr.Feature(layer_defn)
    feature.SetGeometry(geom)
    feature.SetField("ID", index + 1)
    layer.CreateFeature(feature)

ds = None

with open(output_shapefile + '.prj', 'w') as prj_file:
    prj_file.write(spatial_ref.ExportToWkt())
```

I know there is a Polygonize function in QGIS but it provides so much detail and I want just the major features. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use shapefile as output format? A modern format (GeoPackage) would get around this issue.